# "SQLException: Unwrap error" with JDBI and PGJDBC-NG Postgres Driver

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jdbi, pgjdbc-ng

I'm using JDBI to connect to my Postgres db.  This has been working fine. Today I decided to try replacing the native Postgres driver with [PGJDBC-NG](https://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/) driver. Everything is fine until I try my first simple query:

```
jdbi.useExtension(FooDao.class, dao -> {
    dao.insert(e);
});
```

This unfortunately results in:

> org.jdbi.v3.core.ConnectionException: java.sql.SQLException: Unwrap error

Debugging into the app I find the exception occurs in the `customizeHandle` method of JDBI's `PostgresPlugin` class:

```
@Override
public Handle customizeHandle(Handle handle) {
    PGConnection pgConnection = Unchecked.supplier(() -> handle.getConnection().unwrap(PGConnection.class)).get();
    return handle.configure(PostgresTypes.class, pt -> pt.addTypesToConnection(pgConnection));
}
```

The exception is thrown on the first line, in the `unwrap` method. The problem it seems is that with the new driver, `getConnection` returns an instance of [`PGDirectConnection`](https://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/docs/snapshot/javadoc/com/impossibl/postgres/jdbc/PGDirectConnection.html), which is not assignable from `PGConnection`, as the unwrap method call specifies.

Is there a work-around for this? I'm thinking I could just extend `PostgresPlugin` and override the implementation of `customizeHandle` to unwrap using `PGDirectConnection` but I'd prefer not to if possible.

**Edit**: Ugh, can't override `customizeHandle` because `PostgresTypes.addTypesToConnection` isn't public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PostgresPlugin` JDBI is querying for `PGConnection` directly; which is a class only available in the standard driver. So until it's altered to work with NG, it won't.

Although, according to the docs...

> The plugin configures mappings for the Java 8 java.time types like Instant or Duration, InetAddress, UUID, typed enums, and hstore.

but none of this is necessary because `PGJDBC-NG` supports all of these types natively!

#### Solution

Don't use the `PostgresPlugin`